# Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin Need to make layout scrollable

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, scrollview

I have the following axml that doesn't work apparently because I have multible linear layouts.  I need to make this layout scrollable as I have a lot of data that I need to capture.  Nothing I've been able to find has worked.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Parents Information"
                android:id="@+id/btnparents_info" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medical Information"
                android:id="@+id/btnmedical_info" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imageview_participant" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/TextView_name" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="First Name" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/first_name"
            android:text="First Name" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Middle Initial" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength = "1"
            android:id="@+id/mi"
            android:text="M" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Last Name" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/last_name"
            android:text="Last Name" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Suffix" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_suffix" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Address" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:text="Address" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="City" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:text="City" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="State" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/state" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Zip Code" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength = "5"
            android:id="@+id/zip"
            android:text="Zip Code" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Phone" />
        <MaskedEditText.MaskedEditText
            app:Mask="(###) ###-####"
            app:MaskFill="_"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/phone"/>
       </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I have multible linear layouts within the scrollview, I assume that is the problem.  I have several views I will need to do this way.

** UPDATE **

I changed the layout to this"

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="First Name" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/first_name"
            android:text="First Name" />
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Middle Initial" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength = "1"
            android:id="@+id/mi"
            android:text="M" />
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Last Name" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/last_name"
            android:text="Last Name" />
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Suffix" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_suffix" />
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Address" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:text="Address" />
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="City" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:text="City" />
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="State" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/state" />
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Zip Code" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength = "5"
            android:id="@+id/zip"
            android:text="Zip Code" />
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Phone" />
        <MaskedEditText.MaskedEditText
            app:Mask="(###) ###-####"
            app:MaskFill="_"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/phone"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

All I get with this is the first `Textview` and `EditView` side by side, the rest do not display at all but `FindViewById` can apparently find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is Scroll View can only have one direct child :

Solution just wrap all your child layouts into one LinearLayout

```
   <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android: orientation="vertical"
     >
    // Add your multiple linear layouts here ans set orientation for above linear according to your requirement
     </LinearLayout></ScrollView>
```

Good luck!

Revert if this doesn't work

### Update

What i wanted you to do was this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Parents Information"
                android:id="@+id/btnparents_info" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medical Information"
                android:id="@+id/btnmedical_info" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imageview_participant" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/TextView_name" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android: orientation="vertical"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="First Name" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/first_name"
            android:text="First Name" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Middle Initial" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength = "1"
            android:id="@+id/mi"
            android:text="M" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Last Name" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/last_name"
            android:text="Last Name" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Suffix" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_suffix" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Address" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:text="Address" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="City" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:text="City" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="State" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/state" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Zip Code" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength = "5"
            android:id="@+id/zip"
            android:text="Zip Code" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Phone" />
        <MaskedEditText.MaskedEditText
            app:Mask="(###) ###-####"
            app:MaskFill="_"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/phone"/>
       </LinearLayout>
         </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, all I get are the first textview and editview, the rest do not display.  :(

Comment: Updated my answer take a look

Comment: I had tried that some time ago with the same results.  I reapplied the code and discovered a extraneous character embedded in the file preventing the axml from parsing correctly... now it works.  I did not see the error in the output because I didn't scroll down through all the errors ... duh ... Thank you for all the help.